# jquery get the value of a nested item by class

Tags: jquery, html, css, find, filtering

I am trying to figure out how to get the value of a nested item in my html.
My html has the following structure

```
<DIV class=s4-ql id=zz17_V4QuickLaunchMenu>
  <DIV class="menu vertical menu-vertical">
    <UL class="root static">
      <LI class=static><A title="Executive Team description updated" class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Executive Team</SPAN>    </SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background>      <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Finance</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background>    <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Human Resources</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class="static selected">
         <A class="static selected menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Information Technology</SPAN><SPAN class=ms-hidden>Currently selected</SPAN></SPAN></A> 
      <UL class=static>
          <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Calendar</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
          <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Contacts</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
          <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background>  <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Discussions</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
          <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Shared Documents</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
          <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Workspaces</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      </UL></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Legal</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Manufacturing</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Sales</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Purchasing</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Safety</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
      <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Sales/Materials</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
     <LI class=static><A class="static menu-item" href="#"><SPAN class=additional-    background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Traffic</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
    </UL>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

anytime I use the following jquery

```
var siteTitle = $(".s4-ql").find(".menu-item-text").text();
```

I am able to get the first item in the UL, but I can't seem to filter my results so that I can target the s4-sql class and then the static item selected and then the menu-item-text that I need to get. I have tried all kinds of variations on using multiple classes to target the specific item but no luck.

```
var siteTitle = $(".s4-ql.static selected menu-item").find(".menu-item-text").text();
var siteTitle = $(".s4-ql .static selected menu-item").find(".menu-item-text").text();
var siteTitle = $(".static selected menu-item").find(".menu-item-text").text();
var siteTitle = $(".s4-ql .static selected menu-item .menu-item-text").text();
```

none of the above ways are working, this seems so simple but I am not getting it!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - only `li` elements can be the direct children of a `ul`. Your `span` elements will be appearing outside of the `ul`.

Comment: I updated the sniplet using my actual html, was in a hurry and thought it would be faster to convey the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `ul` element can't have `span` tag as a children

```
$(".s4-ql.static selected menu-item")// you forget "." for class in nesting class
```

change in

```
$(".s4-ql.static .selected .menu-item")
```

Comment: there is actually a space in the name of the class:
 .static selected menu-item 
is the name of the class

Comment: You were right, I didn't realize that the class names could not have spaces in them!!! sheesh!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
var siteTitle = $('.s4-ql .menu-item-text').html();
```

Comment: this returns the first item in the UL, I need to filter at the item with the class selector of: static selected menu-item so I can get the currently selected item.